# What is the difference between 'to be able' and 'to be capable'?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What should I use in a good sense or not to show negative impact ?

> I am not able to do that.

or

> I am not capable to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Both options will do fine:

> I am not able to do that.

or

> I am not capable of doing that.

Notice that able is followed by the preposition *to* whereas capable is followed by the preposition *of*.

In first case you don't have the skills or qualities to do that whereas in the second case you don't have the ability, capacity or potential of doing that.

Comment: so using capable will cover ability too?

Comment: @varsha, yes there is little difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to do that-It is generally used when you don't have the power, skill, means, or opportunity to do something.

I am not capable to do that-It is generally used when you don't have ability, fitness, or quality necessary to do or achieve a specified thing.

Comment: what ability indicates here

Comment: ability means क्षमता,योग्यता (in hindi)

actually i have just mentioned the sense where they are used